# Laravel: Associate models without saving in a HasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model like so:

```
class Bill extends Model {
    public function billItems(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BillItem::class);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to create a new bill and associate it with bill items without saving any of them, so that I can save them later if it passes some condition (e.g. if the payment went through).

e.g.

```
$bill = new Bill();

$billItem1 = new BillItem();
$billItem1->name = "T-Shirt";
$billItem1->price = 250;

$billItem2 = new BillItem();
$billItem2->name = "Cap";
$billItem2->price = 174;

// $bill->billItems()->attachWithoutSaving([$billItem1, $billItem2]); // Bit I need help with
// ... 

$paymentIsSuccessful = true; // actual code would be some payment logic
if ($paymentIsSuccessful) {
   $bill->save();
   foreach($bill->billItems as $billItem) {
      $billItem->save();
   }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [manual database transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#manually-using-transactions). The following will rollback all changes if an exception occurs. But it can be changed to `commit` at any point/ condition.

```php
DB::beginTransaction()
try {
  $bill = new Bill();

  $billItem1 = new BillItem();
  $billItem1->name = "T-Shirt";
  $billItem1->price = 250;

  $billItem2 = new BillItem();
  $billItem2->name = "Cap";
  $billItem2->price = 174;

  $bill->billItems()->attach([$billItem1, $billItem2]);

  $paymentIsSuccessful = true; // actual code would be some payment logic
  if ($paymentIsSuccessful) {
    $bill->save();
    foreach($bill->billItems as $billItem) {
      $billItem->save();
    }
  }
  
  DB::commit();
} catch(\Exception $exception) {
  DB::rollback();
  throw $exception;
}
```

Comment: Probably want an `} else { DB::rollBack(); }` on the `if ($paymentIsSuccessful)` (unless that also raises an Exception; hard to say with placeholder code), but otherwise this is a great approach 